# finding distance between two values in multi dimentional arrays in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm new to php and would like to find out the answer to the question

```
          Find two closest objects by distance.

          @param array $objects The list of objects with the name and  coordinates.
          @return array The closest objects names.

          An example:
              php> $obj1 = ['name' => 'a', 'x' => 1, 'y' => 1];
              php> $obj2 = ['name' => 'b', 'x' => 1, 'y' => 2];
              php> $obj3 = ['name' => 'c', 'x' => 10, 'y' => 10];
              php> = findClosest([$obj1, $obj2, $obj3])
              array(
                0 => "a",
                1 => "b",
              )



function findClosest(array $objects)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

I have tried this:

```
<?php
function findClosest(array $objects) {
    function cmp($a, $b) {
        if( ($a["x"] < $b["x"])&&($a["y"] < $b["y"]) ) return -1; //echo "</br>";
    }
    echo usort($objects, "cmp");
    $arrlength=count($objects);
    for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++) {
        print_r($objects[$x]) ; //echo "<br>";
    }
}
findClosest($objects);
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far getting your wished output? Please post your code.

Comment: While we appreciate answering your homework questions, we do best on helping you find out whats wrong with your code. Can you show us something you've tried?

Comment: function findClosest(array $objects)
{
function cmp($a, $b) {
       if(  ($a["x"] < $b["x"])&&($a["y"] < $b["y"]) )   
        return -1;
       //echo  "</br>";
}
echo usort($objects, "cmp");

$arrlength=count($objects);
for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
{
 print_r($objects[$x]) ;
 //echo "<br>";
}


}
findClosest($objects);
?>

Comment: You have to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem to calculate the distance between objects.

Comment: i hoping for a more coding related answers,i see its a tough one to crack but thanks anyways guys . i hope a more experienced person could show me how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate over each possible combination and calculate the distance between this pairs.

```
function findClosest(array $objects) {
    if (count($objects) < 2) return false;

    // distance between $a, and $b
    $fd = function($a, $b) {return sqrt(pow($a['x'] - $b['x'], 2) + pow($a['y'] - $b['y'], 2)); };
    $init = [
        'd' => $fd($objects[0], $objects[1]),
        'a' => $objects[0],
        'b' => $objects[1]];

    // iterate over each combination
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($objects) - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($objects); $j++) {
            $distance = $fd($objects[$i], $objects[$j]);
            if ($distance < $init['d']) {
                $init['d'] = $distance;
                $init['a'] = $objects[$i];
                $init['b'] = $objects[$j];
            }
        }
    }

    // return the smallest distance
    return [$init['a'], $init['b']];
}
```

Comment: getting errors Notice: Undefined offset: 0 

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 

Notice: Undefined offset: 0 

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 

Notice: Undefined offset: 0

Comment: you have to use the function like `$input = [$obj1, $obj2, ...]; $result = findClosest($input);`

Comment: $objects = array(
  "obj1" => array
  (
    'name' => 'a', 'x' => 1, 'y' => 1
  ),

  "obj2" => array
  (
    'name' => 'b', 'x' => 1, 'y' => 2
  ),

  "obj3" => array
  (
    'name' => 'c', 'x' => 10, 'y' => 10
  ),
  
  "obj4" => array
  (
    'name' => 'd', 'x' => 5, 'y' => 5
  ),
  
  "obj5" => array
  (
    'name' => 'e', 'x' => 1, 'y' => 8
  )
);   findClosest($objects);

Comment: This is an assoc array - if you want to use this array, you have to use `array_values`, or the indices are undefined: `findClosest(array_values($objects));`

Answer (score 0):

Note that this will work with any number of arguments/points provided to findClosest finction ($obj4, $obj5...)

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a['distance'] - $b['distance'];
}

function findClosest(array $obj)
{
    $i=0;
    foreach($obj as $key1 => $o1){
      foreach($obj as $key2 => $o2){
        if($key1 !== $key2 && $key1 < $key2){
            $distance[$i]['distance'] = sqrt(pow($o2['x'] - $o1['x'], 2) + pow(o2['y'] - $o1['y'], 2));
            $distance[$i]['first'] = $o1['name'];
            $distance[$i]['second'] = $o2['name'];
            $i++;
        }
      }
    }
    usort($distance, "cmp");
    $closer = array ($distance[0]['first'], $distance[0]['second']);
    return $closer;
}

$obj1 = ['name' => 'a', 'x' => 1, 'y' => 1];
$obj2 = ['name' => 'b', 'x' => 1, 'y' => 2];
$obj3 = ['name' => 'c', 'x' => 10, 'y' => 10];

findClosest([$obj1, $obj2, $obj3]);
```

Comment: Doing it like this, you have some unnecessary overhead - create a new array and the sort function. This would result in `O(n^2 + n log(n))`